# MaxDoubleSliceSum - codility

Tags: c++

I'm trying to solve MexDoubleSliceSum problem **without** Kandane's bidirectional algorithm.

Problem Definition:

> A non-empty array A consisting of N integers is given.
>
> A triplet (X, Y, Z), such that 0 ≤ X < Y < Z < N, is called a double
>   slice.
>
> The sum of double slice (X, Y, Z) is the total of A[X + 1] + A[X + 2]
>   + ... + A[Y − 1] + A[Y + 1] + A[Y + 2] + ... + A[Z − 1].
>
> For example, array A such that:
>       A[0] = 3
>       A[1] = 2
>       A[2] = 6
>       A[3] = -1
>       A[4] = 4
>       A[5] = 5
>       A[6] = -1
>       A[7] = 2
>
> The goal is to find the maximal sum of any double slice.
>
> that, given a non-empty array A consisting of N integers, returns the
>   maximal sum of any double slice.
>
> For example, given:
>       A[0] = 3
>       A[1] = 2
>       A[2] = 6
>       A[3] = -1
>       A[4] = 4
>       A[5] = 5
>       A[6] = -1
>       A[7] = 2
>
> the function should return 17, because no double slice of array A has
>   a sum of greater than 17.

I have figured out following idea:

I'm taking a slice and putting lever (value in the middle that's being dropped) to lowest value included in this slice. If I notice that next value is lowering total sum i'm changing lever to it and reducing sum with values before last lever(including old lever).

```
int solution(vector<int> &A) {
    if(A.size()<4)
            return 0;

    int lever=A[1];
    int sum=-lever;
    int presliceValue=0;
    int maxVal=A[1];

    for(int i=1;i<A.size()-1;i++){
        if(sum+A[i]<sum || A[i]<lever){
            sum+=lever;
            if(presliceValue<0)
                sum=sum-presliceValue;
            lever=A[i];
            presliceValue=sum+lever;
            }
        else
            sum=sum+A[i];

        if(sum>maxVal)
            maxVal=sum;

        }
    return maxVal;
}
```

This solution returns wrong value on few test cases (unfortunately cannot tell what's tested values):

unfortunately i cannot reproduce following error and codility does not share test values.

Failed Test cases

- many the same small sequences, length = ~100,000
- large random: random, length = ~100,000
- random, numbers from -30 to 30, length = 300
- random, numbers form -10<sup>4</sup> to 10<sup>4</sup>, length = 70

Comment: Should your initial values not come from `A[0]` as opposed to `A[1]`?

Comment: since sum is defined as A[X + 1] + ... +A[Z-1] I have ignored border values